# nginx proxy_pass returning same contents for all requests

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I've got a system that's a proxy_pass into a bunch of AWS resources, and as such the IPs are changing all the time. In an attempt to not have to be reloading nginx constantly, I'm moving proxy_pass to use a variable (which is partly working)

Original Block:

```
location /folder/ {
    proxy_pass https://folder.site.com:8888/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
}
```

New Block:

```
location /folder/ {
    resolver 172.19.0.190;
    set $folder_url https://folder.site.com:8888/;
    proxy_pass $folder_url;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
}
```

It's working fine at resolving the site. What it is is an HTML file, which loads a CSS and JS file. My problem is that all 3 files have the exact same contents, which are the HTML contents.

I've got to be missing something stupid, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When variables are used in proxy_pass, if a URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

You have specified the URI as `/` in the `$folder_url` variable, so any URI (e.g. `/folder/foo`) is translated to `/` before passing upstream.

Your original block will translate `/folder/foo` to `/foo` before passing it upstream.

You can use a regular expression `location` block to capture the part of the URI to be sent upstream, for example:

```
location ~ ^/folder/(.*)$ {
    resolver 172.19.0.190;
    set $folder_url https://folder.site.com:8888/$1;
    proxy_pass $folder_url;
    ...
}
```

Note that the order of regular expression `location` blocks is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.